# A Problem aboud using multi-gpu with a two-stage CNN model

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I design a CNN model which has two stages. First stage is generating proposals like `RPN` in Faster RCNN and the second feeds these proposals into the following part.

**It causes error in the second step.**

Accroding the below error information, it seems like the second input is not correctly assigned to the multi GPU.

However, The model works file with single gpu.

```
  File "/home/f523/guazai/sdb/rsy/cornerPoject/myCornerNet6/exp/train.py", line 212, in run_epoch
    cls, rgr = self.model([proposal, fm], stage='two')
  File "/home/f523/anaconda3/envs/rsy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/f523/anaconda3/envs/rsy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 156, in forward
    return self.gather(outputs, self.output_device)
  File "/home/f523/anaconda3/envs/rsy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 168, in gather
    return gather(outputs, output_device, dim=self.dim)
  File "/home/f523/anaconda3/envs/rsy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/scatter_gather.py", line 68, in gather
    res = gather_map(outputs)
  File "/home/f523/anaconda3/envs/rsy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/scatter_gather.py", line 63, in gather_map
    return type(out)(map(gather_map, zip(*outputs)))
  File "/home/f523/anaconda3/envs/rsy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/scatter_gather.py", line 55, in gather_map
    return Gather.apply(target_device, dim, *outputs)
  File "/home/f523/anaconda3/envs/rsy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/_functions.py", line 68, in forward
    return comm.gather(inputs, ctx.dim, ctx.target_device)
  File "/home/f523/anaconda3/envs/rsy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/comm.py", line 166, in gather
    return torch._C._gather(tensors, dim, destination)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

---

PS

my model sciprt shows below. I want my two-stage model can support for multi batch. e.g. the batch size is 4 and every img output 128 proposal, so the proposal size in here is (4*128, 5)

```
def _stage2(self, xs):
    proposal, fm = xs
    if proposal.dim()==2 and proposal.size(1) == 5:
        # train mode
        roi = roi_align(fm, proposal, output_size=[15, 15])
    elif proposal.dim()==3 and proposal.size(2) == 4:
        # eval mode
        roi = roi_align(fm, [proposal[0]], output_size=[15, 15])
    else:
        assert AssertionError(" The boxes tensor shape should be Tensor[K, 5] in train or Tensor[N, 4] in eval")
    x = self.big_kernel(roi)
    cls = self.cls_fm(x)
    rgr = self.rgr_fm(x)
    return cls, rgr
```

Answer (score 1):

I know where I am wrong. Here’s my second stage to feed input

```
cls, offset = self.model([proposal, fm], stage='two')
```

`proposal` is the ROI whose shape is `[N, 5]`, the 1th dim is the batch index. e.g. The batch size is 4, the range of index is `[0,1,2,3]`. And `fm` is the feature map.

When I use the mult-gpu like 2 gpu. the `proposal` and `fm` will be split into two branch and feed into two gpu. However the batch index range still be `[0,1,2,3]`, then cause a index error and raise gpu error.

What I do is add a line before roi_align like below:

```
from torchvision.ops import roi_align
proposal[:, 0] = proposal[:, 0] % fm.size(0) # this make multi-gpu work
roi = roi_align(fm, proposal, output_size=[15, 15])
```